# Could you provide a tone of a community in addition to the description? Perhaps a link to a wiki page for each community?

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users

Could you provide a tone of a community in addition to the description? Perhaps a link to a wiki page for each community?

I've been reading StackExchange for a few years as I've googled technical answers. I joined in the last week. The first question I asked was put on hold in a non technical area. I think the reasons for that are best documented in a FAQ or wiki style answer. The comment putting the question on hold should have a link to that information.

Comment: Did you look at the help center pages, especially the "how to ask" and "what is on topic" pages available on each site?

Comment: It would seem like a link would be the most appropriate way to communicate that

Comment: There is a link to the help center in the close notice.

Answer (score 10):

If you've been reading SE for a few years, you should be aware:

- the Help Center has information on what's on-topic (and what's not) for each SE site
- subjective questions are usually off-topic on all SE sites

Your question ["What should I make for dinner?"](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/62251/what-should-i-make-for-dinner-tomorrow) is completely subjective and it's specifically off-topic for cooking.SE - there's a note on the side of the Ask a Question page that says "...requests for recipes are considered off topic, and will be closed."  Also on the side of the Ask a Question page is a link to the Help Center with it's on- and off-topic information.